# Save SharePoint list item view form as a word document

Tags: 2013, export, word, view-item

I have a view form in SharePoint 2013, and I am trying to create a button that will export the form into a MS word document.

So really I am trying save a SharePoint form to a word file. Is that possible?

Comment: Are you open to custom coding?

Comment: Yes if it gets the job done and i get the script I can try it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option you can try

1. [Create a Word Template](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-template-86a1d089-5ae2-4d53-9042-1191bce57deb?ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US) Document - Which matches exactly as your View Form
2. [Add a button](http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2012/07/invoke-server-side-code-on-sharepoint.html)
3. On button click - Invoke server side code which uses [Open XML SDK](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/666751/Use-OpenXML-to-Create-a-Word-Document-from-an-Exis) to read the list item and create a new document based on the Word Template.

Comment: this seems a little complex,is this the only way around it?